# WSDL XML rendered by 'ADOM XML v4' in Delphi XE2

Tags: xml, macos, web-services, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have been trying to implement a very simple webservice running under OSX ( and windows) with XE2, but it seems that the XML that 'ADOM XML v4' generates/renders for the webservice is invalid in some way.

The only obvious difference I noticed compared to what is generated with 'MSXML' is that the encoding seem to be set to 'UTF-16LE' no matter what I try to change.

Anyone run in to the same problem and know how to fix it?

Update:

The easiest way to recreate this is to create a trivial 'SOAP Server Application' and change the generated WebModuleUnit to the following:

```
unit WebModuleUnit1;
interface
uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Web.HTTPApp, Soap.InvokeRegistry,
  Soap.WSDLIntf, System.TypInfo, Soap.WebServExp, Soap.WSDLBind, Xml.XMLSchema,
  Soap.WSDLPub, Soap.SOAPPasInv, Soap.SOAPHTTPPasInv, Soap.SOAPHTTPDisp,
  Soap.WebBrokerSOAP, Xml.xmldom, Xml.adomxmldom;

type
  TWebModule1 = class(TWebModule)
    HTTPSoapDispatcher1: THTTPSoapDispatcher;
    HTTPSoapPascalInvoker1: THTTPSoapPascalInvoker;
    WSDLHTMLPublish1: TWSDLHTMLPublish;
    procedure WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
      Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  WebModuleClass: TComponentClass = TWebModule1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  WSDLHTMLPublish1.ServiceInfo(Sender, Request, Response, Handled);
end;

initialization
DefaultDOMVendor := 'ADOM XML v4';
// DefaultDOMVendor := 'MSXML';
end.
```

Using DOMVendor 'MSXML' the service works, but using 'ADOM XML v4' it blows up.

Added this to QC please vote for it if you feel webservices on OSX is important.
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=99412

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to activate the XMLDocument before setting its XML...

Let's show the code I mean:

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  xmldoc1.Active := False;
  xmldoc1.XML.Text := '<root><child>value</child></root>';
  xmldoc1.Active := True;
  s := xmldoc1.XML.Text;
  ShowMessage(s);
end;

procedure TForm1.btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  xmldoc1.Active := False;
  xmldoc1.Active := True;
  xmldoc1.XML.Text := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + sLineBreak + '<root><child>value</child></root>';
  s := xmldoc1.XML.Text;
  ShowMessage(s);
end;
```

With btn2Click, I have:
[image]
With btn3Click, I have:
[image]

As I see the BOM for the first, but not with the second, I think it's ok...

If any insert/update with a node on the TXMLDocument resets it to **UTF-16LE**, you can still replace the first line just before exporting the XML:

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  xmldoc1.Active := False;
  xmldoc1.XML.Text := '<root><child>value</child></root>';
  xmldoc1.Active := True;
  // do what you need

  //before getting the xml
  xmldoc1.XML[0] := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  s := xmldoc1.XML.Text;
  ShowMessage(s);
end;
```

Comment: I did try that to start with, to change the ?xml line, but that didn't help.
As the XML is generated 'under the hood' by the webservice components I only have a few places to hook in.

Best would be if there was anyway to get ADOM to generate correct XML.